# How to add spark service in IBM watson studio?

Tags: ibm-watson

there is no spark service under define computer engine while creating a new project.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bb90d.png)

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8x1a.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bb90d.png)

And no option for R and SCALA under language, and spark version and spark service is not there
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bb90d.png)